# How to get div's content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My div has a styling `position:absolute`, and as a result, it doesn't expand if the content is higher than it's height.

Therefore, I thought that a solution would be if I find what the is the actual content's height, and assign the height to the `div` with the `position:absolute` styling.

Any idea how to do it? or maybe an idea how to make an `absolute` `div` to expand according to its content.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having `position: absolute` shouldn't prevent it from expanding to fit the content, as long as you don't set a specific height on it. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/vPMDh/

Comment: If the elements inside the div are floating, make sure you're applying some kind of clearfix

Comment: can you add a fiddle so we can actually have a look at your Problem. maybe more eyes reviewing your code will see whats wrong in the first place

Comment: that's weird.. I have double checked it, and all I have is min-height.
the divs that are inside the div which it's position:absolute are also position:absolute, maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awful way to get the height of the container. We're basically cloning the whole div, setting the position so that it has height, checking that height, and then removing it:

```
$(function () {
    var clone = null;
    alert( clone = $('.test').clone().css('position', 'static').appendTo(".container").height());
    clone.remove();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vPMDh/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, I've suffered from that problem enough times to need this hack. Setting the height of a div equal to the height of another div, but it's positioned absolutely. I've always looked for a better way, but haven't found one yet.

Comment: well, was thinking for hours... didn't want to use this kind of solution, but I just can't find another one

Answer (score 3):

`Element.scrollHeight` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It should expand even if being absolute.
check you don't have a height: xxpx

if so, change it to min-height

Comment: that's weird.. I have double checked it, and all I have is min-height. the divs that are inside the div which it's position:absolute are also position:absolute, maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

use a clearfix hack. [heres the link](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

and add clearfix to you div

example

in your style sheet

```
<style>
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
</style>
```

... 
and in your div add **clearfix** the class

```
<div class="clearfix">
   //some html tags
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't find out how to use it >.<

Comment: answer revised.. example added

Comment: I'm afraid it's a very very long one. In addition, someone here has already posted a solution, so I'm going to use it. Thanks for the good will!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25985/discussion-between-kfirba-and-pixeltracer)

Answer (score 0):

As you've said `"it doesn't expand if the content is higher than it's height."` I guess you have a fixed height set on it.. if you do need this for some reason try using `min-height` instead.

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZbhK/).

Comment: that's weird.. I have double checked it, and all I have is min-height. the divs that are inside the div which it's position:absolute are also position:absolute, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @kfirba yes that would be why. Have at look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BZbhK/1/ . You'll notice that the wrapper around the div should show a blue background but it cannot determine the hight of its inner content. I tend to stay away from absolute positioning (unless i need a floating div).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="classname">

Some content....


<p style="clear:both">&nbsp</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributing your question. If you use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var x = $("#container").height();
 alert(x);

//if not works then 
  var y = $("#container").outerHeight();
  alert(y);

});
```

I think it is easy as clean code to find the height of any div if you do not apply the div's height too.

Answer (score 0):

similar solution to @MattDiamant, but with vanilla JS and without creating a clone:

```
function getDivHeight(posAbsoluteDiv) {
   const heightBackup = posAbsoluteDiv.style.height;

   posAbsoluteDiv.style.height = 'auto';

   const contentHeight = posAbsoluteDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;

   posAbsoluteDiv.style.height = heightBackup;

   return contentHeight;
}
```